# Indian passport holder, Temporary Resident in Canada, wanting to visit USA

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, canada

I'm an international student at a Canadian University, holding an Indian passport (previous stamps on my passport - Malaysia, Singapore, Canada). I want to visit the US for a short vacation. Is it advisable to apply from Canada? Any advantage/disadvantage of applying at a US consulate in Canada?

Answer (score 1):

Whilst it is technically possible to apply for a US visa at any consulate in any country, it is generally recommended to apply in either your country of citizenship, or the country you currently reside in.

As you are currently a resident of Canada, you are able to apply in Canada.  There is no disadvantage do doing that over applying in India, other than the fact they will also want to see your Canadian visa and entry stamp as proof that you are legally in Canada.

When obtaining an appointment, you will have the option to select that you are a current resident of Canada - you should select that you are as it will make it much easier to get an appointment.